# Recreating an Issue tracker by following along and stuck on getting new issues to pop up. Even though code is the same as video

Tags: javascript, issue-tracking, bug-tracking

I am following along in a video and my code is exactly the same as video, however his works and mine does not. I am about 52 mins in and almost done but when I try to create a new issue, nothing comes up. It just refreshes.  It doesn't fetch the issue as it should, and show it. I am generally just looking for some direction, and how to get through this little hurdle. Thank you in advance, and please let me know if you need more info!

video for reference:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYq9J-Eur9U

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Bug Tracker</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body onload ='fetchIssues()'>
   

<div class="container">
    <h1>JS IssueTracker <small>by Devin Latham</small></h1>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h3>Add New Issue:</h3>
        <form id="issueInputForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="issueDescInput">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="issueDescInput" placeholder="Describe the issue ...">

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="issueSeverityInput">Severity</label>
               <select id="issueSeverityInput" class="form-control"l>
                    <option value="Low">Low</option>
                    <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                    <option value="High">High</option>

               </select>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="issueAssignedToInput">Assigned To</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assignedToInput" placeholder="Enter responsible ...">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="issueList">  
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy Devin Latham</p>
    </div>
</div>

    

    <script> src="https://chancejs.com/chance.min.js"</script>

    <script
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script> src="main.js"</script>

</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
document.getElementById('issueInputForm').addEventListener('submit', saveIssue);

function saveIssue(e){
    const issueDesc = document.getElementById('issueDescInput').value;
    const issueSeverity = document.getElementById('issueSeverityInput').value;
    const issueAssignedTo = document.getElementById('issueAssignedToInput').value;
    const issueId = chance.guid();
    const issueStatus = 'Open';

    let issue = {
        id: issueId,
        description: issueDesc,
        severity: issueSeverity,
        assignedTo: issueAssignedTo,
        status: issueStatus

    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('issues') == null){
        let issues = [];
        issues.push(issue);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    } else {
        let issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
        issues.push(issue);
        localStorage.setItem('issues', JSON.stringify(issues));
    }

    document.getElementById('issueInputForm').reset();
    
    fetchIssues();

    e.preventDefault();

}

function fetchIssues(){
    let issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('issues'));
    let issuesListe = document.getElementById('issuesList');

    issuesList.innerHTML = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < issues.length; i++){
        let id = issues[i].id;
        let desc = issues[i].description;
        let severity = issues[i].severity;
        let assignedTo = issues[i].assignedTo;
        let status = issues[i].status;

        issuesList.innerHTML += '<div class="well">' +
                                '<h6>Issue ID: ' + id + '</h6>'
                                '<p><span class="label label-info">' + status + '</span></p>' +
                                '<h3>' + desc + '</h3>' +
                                '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>' + severity + '</p>' +
                                '<p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>' + assignedTo + '</p>' +
                                '<a href="#" onclick="setStatusClosed(\''+ id + '\')" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>' +
                                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteIssue(\''+ id + '\')" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>' +
                                '</div>'

                                

    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase It will just not load the app correctly.  It's like the code i have in there doesn't work properly.  Although, I am fairly sure it's exactly like the video i was following along with.